# CakePHP how to create hasMany data without knowing the foreign key in one saveAll?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I was hoping to create and save the associated data like what I did with belongsTo data - the associated data are created on the fly and foreign ID is also generated and saved on the fly by a single call to saveAll or saveAssocated which has transaction built-in.

But this seems not the case for data in hasMany relationship. Take User and Comment as example. Comment has user_id as the foreign key.

It seems that I cannot save User $data by using single saveAll($data) on User

```
Array(
    'name' => 'Jack',
    'email' => 'jack@abc.com',
    'Comment' => array(
         array(
            'title' => 'I like this article.'
         )
    )
)
```

I read some docs. It seems that I need to mention the user_id as the foreign key for the Comment data to create correctly.

If that's the case, since I don't have user ID until it's created, it seems that I need to code to let SAVE happen twice.

I really think that I am missing something. There should be a CAKE way for doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done automatically by Cake as long as you follow the conventions and format the data accordingly. For `hasMany` associations, the main model data, and the associated model data, need to be set on string keys on the same level, like

```
array
(
    'User' => array(),
    'Comment' => array()
)
```

Also note that

> The saveAll function is just a wrapper around the saveMany and
>   saveAssociated methods. it will inspect the data and determine what
>   type of save it should perform. If data is formatted in a numerical
>   indexed array, saveMany will be called, otherwise saveAssociated is
>   used.
>
> This function receives the same options as the former two, and is
>   generally a backwards compatible function. It is recommended using
>   either saveMany or saveAssociated depending on the case.

So either will do.

Long story short, the model data needs to be separated and indexed by string keys, it's essentially the same format as a `find()` call would return it. That way Cake will know that it needs to save associated data, and will automatically insert the foreign key for the `Comment` records.

```
array
(
    'User' => array
    (
        'name' => 'Jack',
        'email' => 'jack@abc.com'
    ),
    'Comment' => array
    (
        array
        (
            'title' => 'I like this article.'
        )
    )
)
```

See also

- **[Cookook > Models > Saving Your Data > Associations: Linking Models Together > hasMany](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany)**
- **[Cookook > Models > Saving Your Data > Model::saveMany()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array)**
- **[Cookook > Models > Saving Your Data > Model::saveAssociated()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array)**
- **[Cookook > Models > Saving Your Data > Model::saveAll()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array)**

Comment: Thank you! I actually made 2 mistakes. One is what you pointed out. The other is a "notempty" field rule in one ossocaited model. I actually need this field to hold empty value. Now it's working.

Comment: Can you do this with multiple Users and multiple Comments for each User at the same time?

Comment: Yes you can. Just pass multiple sets of what is shown above as numerically indexed array, and use `saveMany()` with the `deep` option set to `true`, see **[Cookook > Models > Saving Your Data > Model::saveMany()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array)** @geoidesic